# Read text file from resource folder and populate jTextArea (NetBeans Java)

Tags: java, resources, readfile, netbeans-8

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");   
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("DBase.dat").getFile());
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        result.append(line).append("\n");                        
    }
    jTextArea1.setText(result.toString());
    scanner.close();    
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

}
```

I am new to JAVA and netBeans I am using this code to read a text file from resources folder and then populate jTextArea from that file. But I am getting Errors. I want to read textfile line by line not all the text at once...
Please Help me what should I do. 
I am pasting a picture too...
[Project Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF5dx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like that:

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("DBase.dat").getPath());
```

Comment: You could also try printing classLoader.getResource(".").getPath() to see if it really points to the directory in which your file is. Normally, it's /resources, but it's better to check